# Concurrent load handling in Django

Tags: django, nginx, load-balancing, task-queue

I am using Django for my new web project. Its basically a Quora clone. Lets say I have a question and Upvote button below it. if around 8-9k people simultaneously click on that Upvote button(of the same question), how can I handle it? I am using Nginx as a front-end server and Apache as back-end server? What should I be using to handle that amount of load?

Comment: Do you have any specific issues with load? And I wonder why you need both Apache and nginx.

Comment: Actually I am using nginx to serve media files and Apache for server requests.

Comment: Not any specific issues, just how to handle the load when around 8-9 thousand people click on the upvote button of the same question.

Comment: This question is too broad. It will depend on a number of factors none of what you have given any details of. If you were running this on a 512MB vps then maybe 90% of the requests might time out. If your infrastructure can handle it then your question will be up voted 8-9K times. If this is a new side project I dont think this will be a problem you need to worry about in the beginning.

Comment: No actually its not a side-project and the terms "Quora Clone" are just for understanding my project is not exactly a clone but a bit different then it. And yes regarding my infrastructure I ll be using Linode server with 4GB RAM.

Comment: Can you please tell me which things I should be using, for example I have to use a Task Queue here or any other thing.

Comment: you dont need anything from outside, just write your code, make sql updates, if you have issues like under 3 upvote clicks, the score is gone up by 4, then poste the code and we will try to help

Comment: I have not deployed my project yet. Its still under development. Means according to you I don't need anything else for handling a load of thousands of users on the same Upvote button(of same question)?

Comment: what do you think you need? what is your worry about this load?

Comment: Means do I need something like queues for handling that amount of load? How can Django handle such load? I am worried about it. @doniyor

Comment: 8-9k people clicking on the same button is just nothing to worry about. we handle 200-300k loads and no problems inside django, it is more your server infrastructure to worry about.

Comment: Build your project and worry about optimizing and scaling later. Its cheap to add an extra server into a cluster.

Comment: @doniyor: What server infrastructure will be I be requiring for it? A short list will do.

Comment: Application Server, Database server

Comment: if you face >300k load, then you need more webservers and a loadbalancer between them. plus more database servers. for now, you dont worry about it, first finish the site, deploy it and watch it with e.g newrelic to see how it goes

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on how you store the votes. Before even worrying about the load on the webserver you must make certain that you are not having a race condition.

Given that you don't, an easy boost can be to cache the votes submitted to a key-value store (e.g. Redis) or even better use it as an aggregator if you have a normalised database.

Another option is to use Celery's asynchronous tasks to queue the votes.

Comment: I use celery as well, because I want persistence. People often don't notice a delay in actual vote count, if there is one, as long a you fake it on the front end.

Comment: I didn't get the concept of caching here actually. Can you please elaborate? @Tiphareth

Comment: Actually I am using AJAX for the async calls via front-end to Django. Will it be okay for heavy load? @MarkGalloway

Comment: Instead of storing each new vote in the database, you can use redis' incr on the dictonary key (vote__id for example, with the total number of votes as its value). Then have a Celery periodic_task or a cronjob to periodically dump the votes in your database. Your view can retrieve votes either from redis or the database. This approach is way faster and guaranties that you will have no race conditions. @cold_coder

Comment: So what about the feeds? If the other user is seeing the same quest then the count wont be exact. How to resolve that?

Comment: If you retrieve the votes from redis, they will always be up-to-date, since there is where you first store them. If you retrieve the votes from the database they will be outdated by a maximum of the period of the celery's periodic_task. In either case the count will always be exact.

Comment: Yeah it sounds great! Is there any alternative to Redis or its the best at a startup level?

Comment: Means I can directly use the vote_id and increment the count of that object from database. But is redis fast so that we can use it? It may sound as silly question,but please help!

Comment: In a similar app what I did was to dedicate a redis db to counting, using the ids as keys with a simple if case to initialise non-existing keys with the value 1, else incr() for the existing ones. In my use case, I dumped the results every morning in the database for archiving purposes. On the other hand if you update directly the database, be careful to wrap the code in a transanction, because you need to retrieve first the old count before increamenting it, and without using raw SQL to do so, it will lead to a race condition. @supercold_coder

Comment: But what if we use QuerySets API instead of raw? How to handle race condition there? @Tiphareth

Comment: user A fetches count=102;
user B fetches count=102;
user A votes -> count=103;
user B votes -> count=103, not 104!

if your RDBMS supports transactions, or you use redis' incr() this won't happen

Comment: But I ll update the values by taking the id after the click on vote, so it wont happen @Tiphareth

Comment: Can you please help? @Tiphareth